# maven release deploy twice and fail

Tags: maven, deployment, release

Hi I have a problem with only one project, while release it fails wiht Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase: Bad Request.
In log I see that it wanted to deploy same artifact second time.
it was working before Ive updated maven to 3.3.3
maven-source-plugin - 2.4
Here is my pom

`<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>maven-depmgt-pom</artifactId>
        <groupId>my.parent</groupId>
        <version>4.0.0-beta-11-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>my.groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>my.artid</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-beta-11-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Che Terminal</name>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:myorg/myproj.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:myorg/myproj.git</developerConnection>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
        <url>https://github.com/myorg/myproj</url>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <project.go.build.dir>${project.build.directory}/go</project.go.build.dir>
        <project.zip.dir>${project.build.directory}/dir/terminal</project.zip.dir>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <updateOnly>false</updateOnly>
                    <descriptor>${project.basedir}/src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <copy file="index.html" todir="${project.zip.dir}" />
                                <copy file="term.js" todir="${project.zip.dir}" />
                                <copy file="server.go" todir="${project.go.build.dir}" />
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-terminal-bin</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <copy file="${project.go.build.dir}/terminal" todir="${project.zip.dir}" />
                                <chmod file="${project.zip.dir}/terminal" perm="+x" />
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile-websocket</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>go</executable>
                            <workingDirectory>${project.go.build.dir}</workingDirectory>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>get</argument>
                                <argument>github.com/myorg/myprj</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile-pty</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>go</executable>
                            <workingDirectory>${project.go.build.dir}</workingDirectory>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>get</argument>
                                <argument>github.com/myorg/pty</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile-server</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>go</executable>
                            <workingDirectory>${project.go.build.dir}</workingDirectory>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>build</argument>
                                <argument>-o</argument>
                                <argument>terminal</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>`

Comment: run it with `-e` and post the exception stacktrace

Comment: so as I can't perform release again now, I;ve tried to checkout tag and execute mvn -e clean deploy which gives me same error (because that tag is already deployed) http://pastebin.com/jjvBBsbE

Comment: here is actual output where it was failed http://pastebin.com/c5fvxkeE

Comment: could you also post the output of `mvn help:effective-pom` ?

Comment: effective pom http://pastebin.com/Y4kt5c4V

Comment: btw all other projects are ok with same parent, only this one is failing

Comment: The error message `org/eclipse/che/terminal/che-websocket-terminal/4.0.0-beta-10/che-websocket-terminal-4.0.0-beta-10.zip. Return code is: 400, Re` says you already have already a release in your nexus...you can't make the same release two times...

Comment: yes because it trying to deploy second time. this happen each new release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem could be in incorrect maven-assembly-plugin configuration.
Effective pom shows

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>make-assembly</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
          <updateOnly>false</updateOnly>
          <descriptor>/Users/sj/dev/src/codenvy/che-websocket-terminal/src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
          <tarLongFileMode>gnu</tarLongFileMode>
          <useJvmChmod>true</useJvmChmod>
          <recompressZippedFiles>false</recompressZippedFiles>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
      <updateOnly>false</updateOnly>
      <descriptor>/Users/sj/dev/src/codenvy/che-websocket-terminal/src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
      <tarLongFileMode>gnu</tarLongFileMode>
      <useJvmChmod>true</useJvmChmod>
      <recompressZippedFiles>false</recompressZippedFiles>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

I assume it means artifact generated two times.

Correct configuration should be:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <updateOnly>false</updateOnly>
                        <descriptor>${project.basedir}/src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```